# MySQL Order By Help!

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I am looking to do an order by in a certain order.  I know I can modify the entire database but I would then need to modify the entire code base.

What I am have, is a column in a table 'games' called 'status'.

So...

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM games 
ORDER BY status ASC  -- Will retrieve results going from 0 then 1 then 2
```

What I am looking for is to be able to order it by 1 then 0 then 2.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, using a [CASE expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html):

```
  SELECT g.* 
    FROM GAMES g
ORDER BY CASE g.status 
           WHEN 0 THEN 1
           WHEN 1 THEN 2
           WHEN 2 THEN 3
         END
```

Using [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
  SELECT g.* 
    FROM GAMES g
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(g.status, '0,1,2')
```

Using [FIELD function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
  SELECT g.* 
    FROM GAMES g
ORDER BY FIELD(g.status, 0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: this would have been the correct answer, but the OP asked for order 1,0,2

Comment: @ajacian81: The comment before that contradicts, but I think the consistency of the examples gives enough of an idea for how to change to suit needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FIELD() :

```
SELECT *
FROM games
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 1, 0, 2)
```

But it might be better to explain a bit more what you want to do, i.e. what your table contains.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post the same method as OMG Ponies did, so +1 there.  Here's the helpful site where I learned this technique:

http://www.shawnolson.net/a/722/mysql-arbitrary-ordering.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have a validation table for the status column, called something like VAL_GAME_STATUS.  GAMES.STATUS would be a foreign key to VAL_GAME_STATUS, and VAL_GAME_STATUS migt look like

```
CREATE TABLE VAL_GAME_STATUS  -- Oracle format - modify as needed for other DB
  (STATUS      NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
   DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   SORT_ORDER  NUMBER NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

Given this, the query to fetch sorted results from GAMES becomes

```
SELECT g.*
  FROM GAMES g
INNER JOIN VAL_GAME_STATUS s
  USING (STATUS)
ORDER BY s.SORT_ORDER;
```

The disadvantage here is that you need to do a join to get the data sorted, but it's a minor hit as VAL_GAME_STATUS is a small table which can probably be held in memory.  The advantage is that you can change the sort order on the fly without touching your code.  Adding new status values with an appropriate sort order is also easily done.

Share and enjoy.